# Hive partition insert error with bash

Tags: bash, apache, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have two tables in Hive :
One of them is an external temporary table created from a csv file. The other table is partitioned by a field called import_date, which is a bigint representation of a date.

When I try to insert into the main table from the temporary table (into a specific partition), I get the following error :

FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10006]: Line 1:51 Partition not found ''1477958400000''

This is my insert statement :

```
"insert into table schema.target_table partition(import_date=1477958400000) select blah, blah, blah from schema.target_table_temp;"
```

The really weird part is that this works if I type that in manually into the hive cli after initializing it with "hive".

For some reason, this refuses to work in my bash script (I also tried echoing the command and piping it into hive, but it also fails). If I save that line to an .hql file and type in hive -f ./something.hql, it produces the same error.

I don't quite understand why it works if I enter it manually after initializing the hive cli with the "hive" command.

I've also tried with import_date being a bigint and string, but it makes no difference. I tried many things, but this insert into a partition command just doesn't work for me.

Comment: `insert overwrite table schema.target_table partition(import_date=import_dt) select blah, blah, blah, '1477958400000' as import_dt from schema.target_table_temp;` ?

Comment: Yeah I tried that.


syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: which hive version?

Comment: Hive Version 1.2.1.2.3.2.0-2950

Comment: Did you have any luck with `beeline` i.e. the thin JDBC client? That one should be less sensitive to configuration glitches etc.

Comment: Is that standard with Hive? I'll check and see if we have it installed.

Comment: Thanks Beeline worked!